# Can some one explain what does it mean by the words "integral over $R$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, terminology

The **integral closure** of a commutative unit ring $R$ in an extension ring $S$ is the set of all elements of $S$ which are **integral over $R$**. It is a subring of $S$ containing $R$.

Can someone explain what does it mean by the words **integral over $R$**?

Comment: Root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element $x \in S$ is [integral over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element) $R$ if there is a *monic* polynomial $P(T) = T^n + a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_1 T+a_0 \in R[T]$ such that
$P(x) = 0.$

---

(Non-)examples:

1) Any element of $R$ is integral over $R$.

2) But $1/2 \in S = \Bbb Q$ is not integral over $R = \Bbb Z$ (it is a root of $2T-1$, but this polynomial is not monic ; and no monic polynomial with integer coefficients can have $1/2$ as root).

3) $\pi \in S = \Bbb R$ is not integral over $R = \Bbb Q$.

4) $i \in \Bbb C$ is integral over $\Bbb Z$, being a root of $T^2+1$.

---

Geometric interpretation : if $R \subset S$ is integral, [then](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WM) $\mathrm{Spec}(S) \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is closed (because of the going-up), and it is [surjective](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00GQ).

Comment: In fact a morphism of schemes is integral if and only if it is affine and universally closed, see [[Tag 01WM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WM)].

Answer (score 3):

An element $s\in S$ is integral over $R$ iff there exists a *monic* polynomial $f\in R[x]$ such that $f(s) = 0$ (as opposed to *agebraic*, which doesn't require the polynomial to be monic).

For instance, take $R = \Bbb Z$ and $S = \Bbb R$. Then $\frac12\in \Bbb R$ is *not* integral, because there is no monic polynomial (with integer coefficients) which has $\frac12$ as root. On the other hand, $\sqrt2$ is integral because $x^2 - 2$ is monic. So the integral closure of $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb R$ contains $\sqrt 2$ but not $\frac12$.

Answer (score 3):

the *definition* of "$S$ is **integral** over $R$" is well-explained by the two answers already given. however if you are new to this concept it may be helpful to know the *significance* of this definition.

Informally we may say "$s$ is integral over $R$" means that for any $s \in S$, we have that $R[s]$ is a *finite-dimensional* extension of $R$. That is to say we can find a finite set $s_1, \dots, s_n$ of elements of $S$ such that any element $s'$ of $R[s]$ can be written as a finite sum:
$$
s' = \sum_i r_i s_i
$$
with $r_i \in R$.

once you see the connection between this idea and the requirement that $s$ satisfies a *monic* polynomial over $R$, you will be well on your way to understanding the importance of integrality

Comment: The  first line of the  2nd paragraph may have typo because you wrote $ \ s \ is \ integral \ over \ R \ $ . But I think it should be $ \ S \ is \ integral \ over \ R \ $ i.e. small $ \ s \ $ will be $ \ S \ $

Comment: no, i meant by $s$ a particular element of S. it is not necessarily true that the integral closure of $R$ is finite-dimensional over $R$. for instance the ring of algebraic integers is not finite-dimensional over $\mathbb{Z}$, but every algebraic integer is. whereas $\frac12$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ since it $\mathbb{Z}[\frac12]$ contains all numbers $\frac1{2^n}$